# Reverse seed interest calculation?

Tags: education, percentages

Assuming an apartment was bought at 1.89 million $.

After 5 years it was sold at 2.5 million $.

The percent difference is : `2.5/1.89 = 1.32` => `32%`  increase.

But how can I find the interest (`x`) value where :

```
After 1 years : 1.89 * 1.X
After 2 years : (1.89 * 1.X) * 1.X
After 3 years : ((1.89 * 1.X) * 1.X) *1.x
...
...   5 years : 2.5 million $
```

Is there any formula to calculate reverse interest seed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a $p\,\%$ annual increase, an initial amount $K$ turns into $K'=K\cdot q^n$ after $n$ years (cf. your repeated factors `1.x`), where $q=1+\frac p{100}$. Here we know $K=1.89$, $K'=2.5$ (both in units of mega-dollars) and $n=5$. Then 
$$ q=\sqrt[n]{\frac{K'}K}=\sqrt[5]\frac{2.5}{1.89}=1.057537\ldots$$
and hence $p=100(q-1)\approx 5.75$. Thus we are speaking of roughly $5.75\,\%\text{p.a.}$ of interest.

*Remark:* The "naive" way of simply dividing the $32\,\%$ by the $5$ years yields $6.4\,\%$, which is wrong, but at least it is somewhat a ballpark estimate - perhaps good enough for a mental estimate, and gets significantly wronger if we consider more years or higher annual interest rates.

Comment: I envy your knowledge ..... wow. thanks

Comment: But isn't the 5'th square root is `a*a*a*a*a` ?  I don't see here any increase along the time ( of intreset on interset)....

Comment: @RoyiNamir The very fact that $5.75\,\%$ is less than the naive (or less derogatively: non-compounding) $6.4\,\%$ shows that there is a difference. Just try and compute the price development over time - what do 1.89 mio\$ become after one year at 5.75%? What does *that* become after another year at 5.75%? And *that*? And so on until after 5 years you should arrive at (approximately) 2.5 mio\$